# Django list class instances matching parent

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-views

I'm new to Django, so any help is appreciated. I have one class `Gym` and a second class `Route` (rock climbing gym and climbing routes). Each `gym` can contain multiple `routes`, but each route can only belong to one gym. I can list available gyms and click on one to go to the gym page, but I want to list all of the routes that belong to it and can't figure out how.

```
# /gym/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class Gym(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gym', default='default_route.jpg')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('gym:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
# route/models.py
from django.db import models
from .utils import generate_qrcode

class Route(models.Model):

    Gym = models.ForeignKey('gym.Gym', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    grade = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    hold_color = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='routes', default='default_route.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

```
# gym/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Gym
from route.models import Route

def gym_list_view(request):
    # Can filter this for specific gyms
    qs = Gym.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'gym/index.html', {'gym_list': qs})

def gym_detail_view(request, pk):
    gym_obj = Gym.objects.get(pk=pk)

    # This is where I don't know how to get the routes that belong to the current gym
    routes_obj = Route.objects.get(pk=pk)

    return render(request, 'gym/detail.html', {'gym_object': gym_obj, 'routes_obj': routes_obj})
```

```
# gym/templates/gym/detail.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ gym_object.pk }}
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    Gym ID: {{gym_object.pk }} <br><br>

    <h3> {{ gym_object.name }} </h3>
    {{ gym_object.address }}
    <br><br>

    <h4>Routes</h4>
    route_obj: {{ routes_obj }}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def gym_detail_view(request, pk):
    gym_obj = Gym.objects.get(pk=pk)

    # This is where I don't know how to get the routes that belong to the current gym
    routes = gym_obj.route_set.all()

    return render(request, 'gym/detail.html', {'gym_object': gym_obj, 'routes': routes})
```

Try this

Comment: This worked, thanks! Is there any documentation on using `route_set`? I can't find anything

Comment: Try searching Related Name for FK in django